# Improve query of getting row with max value

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have next tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Customers` (
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Orders` (
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_cust` INT NOT NULL,
    `descr` VARCHAR(40),
    `price` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`id_cust`) REFERENCES `Customers`(`id`)
);
```

One customer can have many orders. I want to get `id_cust` and sum of the orders of who paid the most(one person).
My query:

```
SELECT cust, max_orders_sum
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT MAX(orders_sum) AS max_orders_sum
        FROM (
            SELECT o.id_cust AS cust, SUM(o.price) AS orders_sum
            FROM Orders AS o
            GROUP BY o.id_cust
        ) AS same_query0
    ) AS step1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT o.id_cust AS cust, SUM(o.price) AS orders_sum 
        FROM Orders AS o
        GROUP BY o.id_cust
    ) AS same_query1
    ON (step1.max_orders_sum = same_query1.orders_sum)
);
```

**Main problem:**
as you can see, it has the same parts: `same_query0` and `same_query1`. Is there any way to get rid of them?
Or if you know the better way to reach my goal, please share.
I found one simple solution:

```
SELECT o.id_cust AS cust, SUM(o.price) AS orders_sum
FROM Orders AS o
GROUP BY o.id_cust
ORDER BY orders_sum DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But this is not a direct way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one nice solution:

```
select id_cust, sum(price) from orders group by id_cust having sum(price) = 
(select max(prc) from
(select sum(price) as prc from orders group by id_cust) as tb);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do much better than what you've already done, unless you create a view like

```
create view v_cust_tot as
select  id_cust, sum(price) as cust_tot
from    Orders
group by id_cust
```

With that you'd be able to rewrite your query like this

```
select  id_cust, cust_tot
from    v_cust_tot
where   cust_tot = (select max(cust_tot) from v_cust_tot)
```

This would be an improvement just in the compactness of the query, because I think performances would be the same as the execution plan would be almost identical